# Как писать от имени канала Pyrogram

Tags: telegram, pyrogram

Написал небольшой скрипт для получения новых сообщений в канале и комментирование их от имени моего канала.

```
app = Client('session', api_id, api_hash)

with app:
    me = app.get_me()
    print("Started for", me.first_name)


@app.on_message(filters.chat('mytestshanel'))
async def handler(_, message: Message):
    post = await app.get_discussion_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
    await app.set_send_as_chat(message.chat.id, -1001965630381)
    await post.reply("Крутой пост")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Здесь "-1001965630381" это ID моего канала от имени которого я хочу оставлять комментарии.

Вроде бы все написано согласно документации, но почему то не работает.

```
Telegram says: [400 Bad Request] - [400 SEND_AS_PEER_INVALID] (caused by "messages.SaveDefaultSendAs")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/Telegram/AIComment2/main.py", line 17, in handler
    await app.set_send_as_chat(message.chat.id, -1001965630381)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/chats/set_send_as_chat.py", line 52, in set_send_as_chat
    return await self.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/invoke.py", line 79, in invoke
    r = await self.session.invoke(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 389, in invoke
    return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 357, in send
    RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/errors/rpc_error.py", line 80, in raise_it
    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.BadRequest: Telegram says: [400 Bad Request] - [400 SEND_AS_PEER_INVALID] (caused by "messages.SaveDefaultSendAs")
```

Возможно кто-то сталкивался уже с такой проблемой и знает как ее решить